# trying to build geode native has 3 errors

Tags: vb6, gemfire, geode

I am building geode native according to https://github.com/apache/geode-native/blob/develop/BUILDING.md and getting errors in the build. I wonder if anyone can help? I have to do this because I need a VB6 client, and the prebuilt dll is not strongly signed, a COM interface to expose the dll to VB6 produces the below error after registration in the .Net GAC:

[image]

To build a strongly signed geode native client, I open an admin VS dev command prompt and navigate to a free directory, then:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/geode-native.git
cd geode-native
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DGEODE_ROOT=D:/Geode ../src
```

This works fine, so I move on to:

```
cmake --build . -- /m
```

There are several errors starting with:

`D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\src\tests\cli\DUnitFramework\ClientGroup.cs(22,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\build\tests\cli\DUnitFramework\DUnitFramework.csproj]`

I've tried directly installing Nunit and getting it on the path variable with no luck.

Then there's: `D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\src\tests\javaobject\GetFunctionExeHA.java:38: error: cannot find symbol`

A possible problem with `'MSBUILD-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

3 openSSL errors:

`ms\uptable.asm(1): error A2088: END directive required at end of file [D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\build\dependencies\openssl\openssl-extern.vcxproj]`

`MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : tmp32dll.dbg\x86_64cpuid.asm [D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\build\dependencies\openssl\openssl-extern.vcxproj]`

`NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\ml64.EXE"' : return code '0x1' [D:\GeodeNativeSrc\geode-native\build\dependencies\openssl\openssl-extern.vcxproj]`

I've installed 64 bit CMake, and Cygwin and I'm using VS 2015 on Win 10 ... Thanks for any comment

Comment: `cmake -DGEODE_ROOT=D:/Geode --build .` appears to have worked, without errors, and produced the VS solution file... Now the VS projects won't build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things of concern.

1) Since you are building open source Geode you should not be using the Pivotal.Gemfire reference. The Geode built assembly will be Apache.Geode.

2) The `MSBUILD-NOTFOUND` error is usually a sign that the CMake configure phase was not run in the Visual Studio command prompt. Be sure you launch the VS 2015 64-bit MSBuild command prompt. You should delete your CMakeCache.txt file before you try again.

3) There are `-D` flags you can send to CMake during configure to setup the strong naming. `-DSTRONG_NAME_KEY=/path/to/key` should do the trick.

4) Since there is no binary distribution of Geode is your intent to use Pivotal GemFire? If so you should contact GemFire support and raise this issue.

Comment: Big thanks for your comment, especially 2 & 3. Much appreciated. Actually for 1 & 4 I need a 32 bit version of geode in a strongly signed dll which I can expose via COM to a VB6 app... At some point I may pass this on to Pivotal support as you suggest. Thx again.

Comment: any idea what the Cmake /m optional build flag does? Or how to get Nunit framework into the build path?

Comment: @rupweb the /m flag is for MSBuild to allow Building Multiple Projects in Parallel
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx

Comment: 1) Pivotal does not support or release anything 32-bit GemFire. Geode Native is known to compile in 32-bit but is not supported by the community. If you are trying to compile 32-bit on windows you must use the 32 bit VS 2105 command prompt then. You also need to set `-G"Visual Studio 14 2015"` (notice no Win64) and  `-DBUILD_BITS=32`. We have also found that when compiling form the command line using MSBuild (through CMake or not) you need to pass the `/p:Platform=x86`. If you are successful in building a 32-bit version please consider forking and updating the BUILDING.md with your process.

Comment: @JacobBarrett when you go to the [native client documentation](https://gemfire-native.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/about_native_client_users_guide.html) and hit [download](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gemfire/#/releases/5469) and find the native client, the resulting `prebuilt dll` is called Pivotal.Gemfire.dll as in you point (1) above, and the screenshot (in the question).